# Best way to copy data between databases with Greenplum without losing data

Tags: database, postgresql, copy, greenplum

My database relies on Greenplum copy functions to copy data from source to target databases.

At the moment, I have a process that copies data from a PostgreSQL source using the following copy statement:

```
psql -d ${SRC_DB} -Atc """ COPY ( select * from ${table_name} ) TO STDOUT DELIMITER E'\37' NULL E'' QUOTE E'\36' CSV """  > /base_dir/${SRC_TABLE_NAME}.csv
```

What this function does is copy all of the data locally in order to be copied later to the target database.

This function then copies the data into the target database using the following function:

```
psql -d ${TRGT_DB} -Atc "\copy ${TRGT_TBL} from /base_dir/${SRC_TABLE_NAME}.csv DELIMITER E'\37' NULL E'' QUOTE E'\36' CSV LOG ERRORS SEGMENT REJECT LIMIT 100 PERCENT"
```

I have noticed that, for very large tables over a million records, data will be missing from the target table during the loading process. It seems there is even data loss during the staging process when the data is moved to the CSV. Often there are some issues with special characters being perceived as delimiters.

Is there a way to avoid this loss of data? I have heard some things about binary conversion. How would I use that in the example?

Answer (score 0):

The `COPY` function is not efficient with Greenplum, as it will pull all the data off the segments, and through the Coordinator node, creating a bottleneck.

gpbackup/gprestore uses `COPY`, but more specifically the `ON SEGMENT` option, which will COPY to/from the actual segment in which the data is stored.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum/6/greenplum-database/ref_guide-sql_commands-COPY.html

There are a variety of ways to copy data from a source to target Greenplum cluster.
I would take a look at:

- gpcopy
- gpbackup/gprestore (you can manually copy the backup files from source to target, or you can backup to shared storage such as S3 compatible filesystems, or NFS.

Comment: The issue is that the source database is not Greenplum

Comment: Have you tried pg_dump & pg_restore

Answer (score 0):

We use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to transfer data between greenplum and postgres a schema at a time and haven't noticed any data loss. I've adjusted the commands for a specific table rather than a specific schema. This assumes that the table is the same name in the target database.

```
pg_dump --host=$(SOURCE_IP) --dbname=$(SOURCE_DATABASE_NAME) --username=$(SOURCE_USER) --no-password --table=$(SOURCE_TABLE) --file=\\tmp\\$(SOURCE_TABLE)_data.dmp --format=d --jobs=4 --quote-all-identifiers --compress=9 --no-privileges --no-owner --blobs --data-only
```

```
pg_restore --host=$(TARGET_IP) --dbname=$(TARGET_DATABASE_NAME) --username=$(TARGET_USER) --no-password --format=d --no-privileges --no-owner --data-only --jobs=8 --verbose \\tmp\\$(SOURCE_TABLE)_data.dmp;
```

There is also the possibility to use a FOREIGN TABLE on the Greenplum side to read data from postgres using the postgres_fdw. I've not tried that approach myself as yet.